# Zookeeper resetting connections?

Tags: node.js, networking, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We are having issues with dropped connections in a node-kaka client. It appears that the zookeeper is resetting connections on us. When I run a tcpdump I see the following all over the place when viewed in wireshark:

[image: wireshark trace showing rst]

The source is always one of our zookeeper servers and the destination is our kafka consumer. It appears that our client handles these in most situations just fine. In fact, I'm not at all convinced this is the cause for our failures. But, it does seem odd. I was hoping someone with more experience in how kaka-node, zookeeper, and kafka interact could provide some explanation.

**ADDING SOME DETAILS FROM LOG**

So, I see a few things in the logs. First, there are a ton of the following:

```
2016-03-11 20:26:32,357 [myid:2] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] - Client attempting to establish new session at /10.196.2.106:59300
2016-03-11 20:26:32,358 [myid:2] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@822] - Connection request from old client /10.196.2.106:59296; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
```

Then there are a whole bunch of these:

```
2016-03-12 03:40:49,041 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1527b11827bfcfe, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-03-12 03:40:49,042 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1007] - Closed socket connection for client /10.196.2.106:33197 which had sessionid 0x1527b11827bfcfe
```

The strange thing is that IPs correlate to our secor servers. So, this is probably not related.

Other than that, I do not see anything really out of the ordinary.

Comment: Can you add the zk errors that are logged?

Comment: Added anomalous log entries to post. Thanks @MartinSerrano!